# Deploying WSO2 API Manager .war on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, wso2, cxf

Repository - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

Branch - 2.x-dependency-upgrade

**R**ecently, While working with WSO2 API Manager, I found that some war files are generated and deployed.

To experiment with the war files, I deployed them on tomcat server. Deployment doesn't work and gives `Error` **creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml**.

Detailed Error Log : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c2378967ffcc1bb7a9bb475507120e9

.war file location: *\product-apim\modules\distribution\product\target\wso2am-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT\repository\deployment\server\webapps*

I tried to play with dependencies but with no change in error status.

1. Why does these war files work well with the WSO2 standalone server, but not with the tomcat server ?
2. How could we resolve the dependency issue ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Lets say you have **Wildfly or Tomcat** already running on some instance. Deploying WSO2 on the same server will be better rather than using it on a standalone server. Since many times the load is not that high to go for standalone server dedicated for api management.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `2.x-dependency-upgrade` branch, which is a temporary one. Use `2.x` branch instead.

Those war files need dependencies coming from carbon platform. (You can see lots of `NoClassDefFoundError` errors in the log) So, without those, they won't be working properly.

Comment: 2.x branch is also having the same issue with dependencies(I switch to 2.x-dependency-upgrade to see if it works or not). A lots of `NoClassDefFoundError` are still there with 2.x.

Comment: Yes, you will have to deploy carbon webapp too and put all dependencies including the OSGi runtime jars. That simply means everything in apim zip should be copied to tomcat and configure everything properly. I don't think it's going to be a trivial task unless you know how APIM internals work. I don't think it gives much benefits for the effort it requires.